# ionic transition issue iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a form with angular validation, using `$dirty`
when I accessing that from some page, the validation appear from a sec. like get a bad transition, but it just on iOS, android is working fine.

I tried to search anywhere and cant find the solution, anyone can help?
thank you.

example code :

```
<div class="error-container text-left" ng-show="form.firstName.$invalid && form.firstName.$dirty">
    <p ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required">First name can not be empty</p>
</div>
```

but at the first time load the page, it still appear at the first load for couple sec.

Comment: can you post some code my man? or make a codepen  my man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add ng-hide in your div class.

```
    <div class="error-container text-left ng-hide" ng-show="form.firstName.$invalid && form.firstName.$dirty">
        <p ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required">First name can not be empty</p>
    </div>
```